# mapper_parsing_exception error for JSON array while adding into ES

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-sdk

I am trying to create object array into ES using below code. Rest of the parameters are inserting properly except this parameter. I think this because of datatype problem

```
 var body = {
      "expertise": [{
          "productName": "solution architecture"
        },
        {
          "productName": "product architecture"
        }
      ]
    }

 client.index({
  index: index,
  type: type,
  body: body
}, function(error, resp, status) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    callback(error);
  }
  console.log('success');
  callback(null, event);
});
```

ES support JSON array datatype https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html then why I am getting such error.

Error i am getting

```
 "errorMessage": "[mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse [expertise]",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "respond (/var/task/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:308:15)",
    "checkRespForFailure (/var/task/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:267:7)",
    "HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:165:7)",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved by changing key.

```
"expertises":  [ // instead of expertise i used expertises
        {
          "productName": "solution architecture"
        },
        {
          "productName": "product architecture"
        }
      ]
```